# Hierarchical fluent interface in C++ with CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, fluent, crtp

I'm trying to build a fluent interface with C++. The code below compiles successfully, but I'm missing one important feature. As you can see yourself, this code is hierarchical and creates a tree of fields starting from a given type. However, I don't know how I can save the parent RootNodeDefinition instance so that I can go up the hierarchy when I finished at a given "nesting level". The commented code at the end of the example code shows what I'm trying to achieve. The code is using the CRTP pattern to be able to call some methods on the derived class. The root node should not have any parent, however all other nested fields will have it (it's the object where the field is defined). If I didn't explain well what I'm trying to achieve just say it to me and I will try to edit the question to satify your doubts. Although the question is related to C#, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072492/designing-fluent-builders-to-create-an-object-graph-in-c-sharp) you can find something similar to my example.

In simpler words, the question is: how can I save the instance of `RootNodeDefinition` (which is typed) and pass it to the `FieldNodeDefinitionInterface` in the constructor as a `parent` argument so that a method like `end()` can returns back to the previous node instance?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename TObjectType, template<typename /*TObjectType*/> class TNodeDefinition>
struct FieldNodeDefinitionInterface;

template<typename TObjectType>
class RootNodeDefinition;

template<typename TObjectType>
struct BaseNodeInterface
{
    virtual ~BaseNodeInterface() = default;

    virtual void convert(const std::string &input, TObjectType *output) = 0;
};

template<typename TObjectType, template<typename /*TObjectType*/> class TNodeDefinition>
struct RootNodeDefinitionInterface : public BaseNodeInterface<TObjectType>
{
    virtual ~RootNodeDefinitionInterface() = default;

    virtual FieldNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition>& registerField(std::string TObjectType:: *field) = 0;

    template<typename TFieldType>
    RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TFieldType, TNodeDefinition>& registerComplexField(TFieldType TObjectType:: *field)
    {
        return static_cast<TNodeDefinition<TObjectType>*>(this)->template registerComplexField<TFieldType>(field);
    }
};

template<typename TObjectType, template<typename /*TObjectType*/> class TNodeDefinition>
struct FieldNodeDefinitionInterface : public BaseNodeInterface<TObjectType>
{
    virtual ~FieldNodeDefinitionInterface() = default;

    virtual RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition>& end() = 0;

    virtual FieldNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition>& asAttribute() = 0;
};

template<typename TObjectType, typename TFieldType, template<typename /*TObjectType*/> class TNodeDefinition>
class FieldNodeDefinition : public FieldNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition>
{
public:
    FieldNodeDefinition(RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition> &parent, TFieldType TObjectType:: *field)
        : field_(field)
        , parent_(parent)
    {
    }

    void convert(const std::string &input, TObjectType *output) override
    {
        TFieldType *field = &(output->*field_);

        // convert the input to a value compatible with TFieldType and store it into field
    }

    RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition>& end() override
    {
        return parent_;
    }

    FieldNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition>& asAttribute() override
    {
        return *this;
    }

private:
    TFieldType TObjectType:: *field_;

    RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, TNodeDefinition> &parent_;
};

template<typename TObjectType, typename TFieldType, template<typename /*TObjectType*/> class TNodeDefinition>
class RootNodeDefinitionProxy : public BaseNodeInterface<TObjectType>
{
public:
    RootNodeDefinitionProxy(TFieldType TObjectType:: *field) : field_(field)
    {
    }

    void convert(const std::string &input, TObjectType *output) override
    {
        builder_->convert(input, &(output->*field_));
    }

    RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TFieldType, RootNodeDefinition>& builder()
    {
        return *builder_;
    }

private:
    TFieldType TObjectType:: *field_;

    std::shared_ptr<RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TFieldType, RootNodeDefinition>> builder_;
};

template<typename TObjectType>
class RootNodeDefinition : public RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, RootNodeDefinition>
{
public:
    void convert(const std::string &input, TObjectType *output) override
    {
        for (auto it = children_.cbegin(); it != children_.cend(); ++it)
            (*it)->convert(input, output);
    }

    FieldNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, ::RootNodeDefinition>& registerField(std::string TObjectType:: *field) override
    {
        std::shared_ptr<FieldNodeDefinition<TObjectType, std::string, ::RootNodeDefinition>> nodeDefinition(new FieldNodeDefinition<TObjectType, std::string, ::RootNodeDefinition>(*this, field));

        children_.push_back(nodeDefinition);

        return *nodeDefinition;
    }

    template<typename TFieldType>
    RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TFieldType, ::RootNodeDefinition>& registerComplexField(TFieldType TObjectType:: *field)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<RootNodeDefinitionProxy<TObjectType, TFieldType, ::RootNodeDefinition>> nodeDefinition(new RootNodeDefinitionProxy<TObjectType, TFieldType, ::RootNodeDefinition>(field));

        children_.push_back(nodeDefinition);

        return nodeDefinition->builder();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseNodeInterface<TObjectType>>> children_;
};

template<typename TObjectType>
class NodeBuilder
{
public:
    RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, RootNodeDefinition>& rootNode()
    {
        builder_.reset(new RootNodeDefinition<TObjectType>());

        return *builder_;
    }

    void deserialize(std::string input, TObjectType *output)
    {
        // In reality, here I should take input and convert it to a graph of nodes using some XML library
        builder_->convert(input, output);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<RootNodeDefinitionInterface<TObjectType, RootNodeDefinition>> builder_;
};

struct Address
{
    std::string street_;
};

struct Author
{
    std::string firstName_;

    Address address_;
};

struct BlogPost
{
    std::string id_;

    std::string title_;    

    Author author_;
};

int main()
{
    NodeBuilder<BlogPost> builder;
    BlogPost blogPost;

    builder
        .rootNode()
        .registerField(&BlogPost::id_).asAttribute().end()
        .registerComplexField(&BlogPost::author_)
            .registerField(&Author::firstName_).asAttribute().end()
            .registerComplexField(&Author::address_)
                .registerField(&Address::street_).asAttribute().end()
            /*.end()
        .end()
        .registerField(&BlogPost::title_).asAttribute()*/;

    builder.deserialize("<blog-post id=\"what_a_nice_id\"><author><firstName>Foo Bar</firstName><address><street>Bar Foo</street></address></author></blog-post>", &blogPost);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the gain of the fluent interface?

Comment: A fluent interface like the one in the example perfectly describes a tree, and in my case I'm building a tree of nodes. For sure I could simply write a lot more code and just have a bunch of objects that gets merged later, but it's not what I want

Comment: Why is the interface statically polymorph and not runtime polymorphic? (Your data seems to be runtime polymorphic anyways) Because recursive function invocation is the natural fit for recursive data structures. Perhaps you can reduce the code by half with some constexpr variadics, but you'll have to choose c++14 to get sane syntax. And choose a compiler that groks it.

Comment: May I suggest creating a more real-life sample? The `testMethod` and `TestInnerInner::fieldC_` is rather overwhelming, and removes all the functional clues we could use to actually understand what the code is trying to achieve

Comment: I renamed the methods to something more similar to a real-world usage. As you can see, to build a tree of nodes you can register a field (that would be a scalar node) or a complex field (which would be a node that has children).

Comment: Good. So it has nothing to do with tests and mockups (I thought of Fluent  Assertions,  likely). I'll have a look later today

Comment: Arrg. I tried. I'm lost. What are you _trying_ to achieve? I think you're overcomplicating in *at least* two dimensions. Are you - by any chance - trying to map XML serialization of an object graph? Can you _show_ how the resultant tree is used? Can you justify the "proxy" (this is probably where you went full-template blind)? If you forget about your code, and state the goal (perhaps with pseudo code of how to use it), I might want to give two competing implementations focusing on different elegances. Right now, I honestly have no clue - it's all tangled.

Comment: Yes, the ultimate goal of this code is to map an XML of any structure to a object. So every node of the XML can be mapped to a property of a class. The proxy is used because a node that has children should create a new instance of RootNodeDefinition, but the template param TObjectType should map the type of the nested field and not the type of the object containing the field. This prevent me to save the instance in the parent children_ vector because of type mismatch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108100/discussion-between-sehe-and-stefano).